# How do I remove an overidden mouseListener?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, joptionpane, mouselistener

I have a JInternalFrame, where I wanted to display a JOptionPane when my JTable was double clicked. I looked around in the internet and found that the only way of doing it was to override mousePressed() method and this is how I did it:

```
tblJobs.addMouseListener (new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e) {
        JTable tbl = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int row = tbl.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());

        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && row != -1) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Double click detected");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The thing is, I also have a button to hide the frame, and when the frame was hidden and re-shown, I found that upon double clicking my JTable, the JOptionPane got displayed twice. The number of times the JOptionPane got displayed seemed to increase along with the number of times I hid and show the frame. My guess is, the mouseListener got called again and again when I hide and re-show my frame. Is there a way of removing the mouseListener that was added in this way? Or is there another way to stop the JOptionPane from displaying more than once? And also, if what my code was stupid in any way, feel free to tell me! :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Or is there another way to stop the JOptionPane from displaying more than once?` == `tblJobs.removeMouseListener(...)` after code line `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dou...`

Comment: as aside double click is accelerator for `XxxTableCellEditor`

Comment: I tried putting the removeMouseListener there and I can't double click again unless I hide and re-show the frame. Also, how do I use the xxxTableCellEditor?

Comment: @c0der thanks that works! I must say that I thought about adding a boolean variable somewhere I just can't put my finger on exactly where I should put it at. Thanks for giving me that idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting a Boolean calss variable `hidden = true` when you hide, `hidden = false` when you unhide ?
Set the first line in `mousePressed()` to `if(hidden) return;`